# I want my bot to send an embed when whenever a user reacts to the above message. Not sure how i would exactly go about doing this

Tags: python, discord.py

@client.command()
async def ra(ctx):

```
embed = discord.Embed(
    colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
    title="RIDEALONG REQUEST",
    description=str(ctx.author.mention) + " IS REQUESTING A RIDEALONG IN SERVER."
)
embed.add_field(name="For FTOs", value="Please react to this message to accept the Ride-Along.", inline=False)
embed.timestamp = datetime.utcnow()
embed.set_footer(text= "This message will automatically delete in two hours")
msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=7200)
await msg.add_reaction('✔️')
await msg.add_reaction('❌')
await ctx.message.delete()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajDLo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You can use different events. Mostly we `wait_for` a `reaction_add`.

***I personally use the following:***

```py
try:
    reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
    while user == client.user:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
    if str(reaction.emoji) == "YourEmoji":
        # Do what you want to do
except Exception: # Timeout can be added for example
    return
```

Here we check that the bot reaction is not counting as a valid reaction but instead a user one.

**The full code would be:**

```py
@client.command()
async def ra(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        colour=discord.Colour.blue(),
        title="RIDEALONG REQUEST",
        description=str(ctx.author.mention) + " IS REQUESTING A RIDEALONG IN SERVER.")
    embed.add_field(name="For FTOs", value="Please react to this message to accept the Ride-Along.", inline=False)
    embed.timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    embed.set_footer(text="This message will automatically delete in two hours")
    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed, delete_after=7200)
    await msg.add_reaction('✔️')
    await msg.add_reaction('❌')
    await ctx.message.delete()
    try:
        reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
        while user == client.user:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add')
        if str(reaction.emoji) == "✔️":
            # Do what you want to do
    except Exception:
        return
```

Comment: So im gonna sound like an idiot, but where would i emplement that code into mine?

Comment: Where at tho? Under which line? Im sorry im new

Comment: See my new edit! You can then add more `if` statements.